# webpack- peer dependency versioning mismatch issue?

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-install, karma-mocha

While installing `npm` packages I am getting peer dependencies versioning mismatch issue.

Error -

> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@2.1.0-beta.12 does not
>   satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>       npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer babel-loader@6.2.4 wants webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
>       npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-webpack@1.7.0 wants webpack@^1.4.0
>       npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@2.0.0-beta wants webpack@>=2.0.3-beta <3

Has any one faced something like this?

package.json file

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "todomvc-app-css": "2.0.4",
  "todomvc-common": "1.0.2"
},
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel": "6.5.2",
  "babel-core": "6.8.0",
  "babel-eslint": "6.0.4",
  "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
  "babel-plugin-__coverage__": "1.11.111",
  "babel-preset-es2015-webpack": "6.4.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.5.0",
  "chai": "3.5.0",
  "cpy-cli": "1.0.0",
  "css-loader": "0.23.1",
  "eslint": "2.9.0",
  "eslint-config-kentcdodds": "6.2.1",
  "eslint-loader": "1.3.0",
  "ghooks": "1.2.1",
  "istanbul": "0.4.3",
  "karma": "0.13.22",
  "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage": "1.0.0",
  "karma-mocha": "1.0.1",
  "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
  "mocha": "2.5.3",
  "npm-run-all": "1.8.0",
  "opt-cli": "1.4.2",
  "rimraf": "2.5.2",
  "style-loader": "0.13.1", 
  "webpack": "^2.0.0-beta",
  "webpack-dev-server": "2.0.0-beta",
  "webpack-validator": "2.1.2"
}
```

Please suggest what exactly, I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message explain everything:

You use `webpack 2` but `karma-webpack` wants to `webpack 1`. You can:

1. downgrade `webpack 2` to version `1` and downgrade `webpack-dev-server` to version `1`.

   or
2. remove `karma-webpack`